# Magento2: How can set duplicate product URL?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-urls, url-key

I want to create each product with duplicate url like

> example.com/custom.

I have tried below things.
I am creating each product with url of custom-productId then it is coming like

> example.com/custom-189

but I want in that way

> example.com/custom

without 404 page.

Can Anyone help me for that.

Comment: You can use URL rewrite.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Yes, I have tried but it gives duplicate url issue. I want to save with above structure. Do you have any example where I can do exactly that in URL rewrite?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Kindly help me for that